# The code fails to compile when I use want to get an ".obj" format triangle mesh

Tags: c++, cgal

## Issue

I used the "GDAL" to read a shpfile file which has one feature. I have got all of this feature's points, and then I want to use the them to generate a ".obj" format mesh file. Interestingly, when I use the "PMP::triangulate_faces(mesh)" to triangulate this mesh, I get some errors like these:

```
CGAL error: precondition violation! 
Expression : vaa != vbb 
File : D:\Programs\dev\CGAL-5.5.1\include\CGAL\Constrained_triangulation_2.h 
Line : 813 
Explanation: Refer to the bug-reporting instructions at https://www.cgal.org/bug_report.html
```

Thus, I abandoned the above mentioned method and replaced it with the "CGAL::convex_hull_3()" method to generate ".obj" format Polyhedron_3. Unfortunately,  this time I couldn't even get the compilation to go through, and I get some errors like these:

```
C2530 "v": References must be initialized   property_map.hpp 304
C2678 Binary "[": no operator found that accepts a left operand of type "const PropertyMap" (or no acceptable conversion)   property_map.h 304
C2678 Binary "[": no operator found that accepts a left operand of type "const PropertyMap" (or no acceptable conversion)   property_map.h 311
```

The code for both methods I used I will give below, I hope both methods will get the appropriate solution

## source code 1

```
namespace PMP = CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing;
typedef K::Point_3 Point;
typedef CGAL::Surface_mesh<Point> Mesh;

Mesh mesh;
for (int k = 0; k < num; k++)
{
  double x = poline->getX(k);
  double y = poline->getY(k);
  double z = poline->getZ(k);
  coordTransform->Transform(1, &x, &y, 0);
  mesh.add_vertex(Point(y - *(center + 1), x - *center, 0 - *(center + 2)));
}                    
string filename = "E:/point/output/泰森多边形/";
filename = filename + "_" + to_string(i)+".obj";
char* path = new char[strlen(filename.c_str()) + 1];
strcpy(path, filename.c_str());
            
mesh.add_face(mesh.vertices());
if (!CGAL::is_triangle_mesh(mesh))//未三角化的三角化
{   
  std::cout << "Input mesh is not triangulated." << std::endl;
  PMP::triangulate_faces(mesh);
}
CGAL::IO::write_polygon_mesh(path, outmesh2, CGAL::parameters::stream_precision(17));
```

## source code2

```
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel K;
typedef CGAL::Polyhedron_3<K>  PHD;

PHD mesh;
vector<Point> points;
for (int k = 0; k < num; k++)
{
  double x = poline->getX(k);
  double y = poline->getY(k);
  double z = poline->getZ(k);
  coordTransform->Transform(1, &x, &y, 0);
  points.push_back(Point(y - *(center + 1), x - *center, 0 - *(center + 2)));

}
CGAL::convex_hull_3(points.begin(), points.end(), mesh);
CGAL::IO::write_polygon_mesh(path, outmesh2, CGAL::parameters::stream_precision(17));
```

## Environment

Operating system (Windows/Mac/Linux, 32/64 bits): Windows 64 bits
Compiler: Visual Studio 2019
Release or debug mode: debug Specific
CGAL version: 5.5.1
Boost version: 1.71.0
Other libraries versions if used (Eigen, TBB, etc.): Eigen 3

## tips:

1.the above code are built on the basis of the main header files have been introduced, if the error is caused by missing header files, I hope you can tell me in detail. 2.if you need to provide experimental data, you can contact me, I can share the data through the wetransfer

Comment: Please try to create a [mre] to show us. And please copy-paste the full and complete build log into your question.

Comment: I will send you my extruded model and the intersected detected model via wetransfer, I think the main reason for the problem is that my extruded model cannot be triangulated, and you can use my model to test my minimal reproducible example

Comment: Notably, the second code need to use the GDAL library, if you want to test it , you should first install the GDAL.

Comment: my wetransfer link is “https://wetransfer.com/downloads/bcf772b2e6b5db4aa3d010c6e742fbe520231011012838/2c18ae" . all of my model file、shpfile file, and my code example can be see in it. Besides, I don't know how to copy-paste the full and complete build log.  I just hope that you can help me to resolve this question, so if you really meed the log about my question, please teach me the method. By the way, my IDE is Visual studio 2019